# Regex for parsing key value pairs with comma and [ ] in the key

Tags: regex, scala

I'm looking to form a regex to parse a string with the below format and seperate it as key value pairs with key as [test,2] and value as 11 and so on..

```
[test,2]=11, [test,3]=12, [test,7]=11, [test,11]=4, [test,16]=5
```

Once the correct regex is formed, I can use it this way to load as key value pairs into a map

```
<REGEX_PATTERN>.findAllMatchIn(input).map(m => (m.group(1).trim(), m.group(2).trim())).toMap
```

Appreciate any pointers with the regex pattern.

Comment: Could you specify type of output `Map`? What is an expected value for first group and second group?

Comment: Hi Sergey, the below answer from Nyavro is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pattern like this:

```
val pattern = "(\\[\\w+,\\d+\\])=(\\d+)(,\\s)?"r
```

Example:

```
scala> val input = """[test,2]=11, [test,3]=12, [test,7]=11, [test,11]=4, [test,16]=5"""
input: String = [test,2]=11, [test,3]=12, [test,7]=11, [test,11]=4, [test,16]=5

scala> val pattern = "(\\[\\w+,\\d+\\])=(\\d+)(,\\s)?"r
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\[\w+,\d+\])=(\d+)(,\s)?

scala> val m  = pattern.findAllMatchIn(input).map(m => (m.group(1).trim(), m.group(2).trim())).toMap
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map([test,2] -> 11, [test,16] -> 5, [test,11] -> 4, [test,3] -> 12, [test,7] -> 11)

scala> m foreach println
([test,2],11)
([test,16],5)
([test,11],4)
([test,3],12)
([test,7],11)
```